# WordPress Navbar not working in Custom Theme

Tags: wordpress

I recently converted a bootstrap html website into a custom WordPress theme for the first time. In my localhost environment the menu works fine. It adds new pages and is fully linked up with WordPress. When I moved to the live host, it stopped working. I don’t think it’s anything to do with bootstrap.css or jquery. I think they are installed correctly. Any advice would be appreciated !

Website is : aehawker.com

Here is how I have added the Menu in the header:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
‘theme_location’ => ‘primary’,
‘container’ => ‘nav’,
‘container_class’ =>’navbar-collapse collapse’,
‘menu_class’    => ‘nav navbar-nav navbar-right’
));
?>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php you should change
*register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'boodstrap2wordpress' ),
        ) );*
To:
*register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary' => __( 'Primary', 'boodstrap2wordpress' ),
        ) );*